# Continuous stitch sculpting blender

Tags: modeling, texturing, sculpting

title says almost anything , is there a way to sculpt stitches continuously  in blender ?
I know that rake option  kinda works but that happens with sliced drops of texture and isn't continuous .[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok in blender we don't do that since blender is a polygon modeling software and not an only sculpting program ,so for doing this

1. you need to have a tillable texture
2. and then you need to model your stitch path with a plane like this :
   [image]
3. then you need to uv map it like this (Using Follow active quads to straighten it)
   [image]
4. then you need to subdivide your stitch path and place it where you want in your model and apply the texture on it , and use a shrinkwrap modifier to project it into your model
   [image]
5. then you need to
6. and then apply everything and subdivide your path more to desired amount and use a displace modifier with uv and your texture , then use solidify modifier a little and join your mesh to your base mesh then remesh it and smooth borders , you should end up with something like this :
   [image]

Comment: Jesus christ ! except those distortions , this was what i wanted , thanks mate .

Answer (score 1):

Another useful option is spacing:

[image]

You can set a space between each step (texture should be cropped to one stroke):

[image]

And don't forget the sample bias:

[image]

Comment: Thats not actually what i wanted , i wanted a continuous pattern with "that" texture without any space in between (kind of bending the texture itself ) , btw thanks